# iPhone Distribution issue

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone app for an equipment dealer who will distribute the App to a number of sub-dealers.  The App is actually a price list type of App where sub-dealers can check the available inventory and prices. I am thinking what is the best way to distribute the App.

App Store - The App may be rejected because of it's "Usability". It is meaningless to users other than the sub-delaers.

Adhoc Distribution - We do not want to go through the process of registering each UDIDs. It will also be very much challenging for the sub-delaers to install the .ipa files.

Is there any better alternatives for us? I have read about custom B2B apps. Will it be helpful for our requirement?

Comment: I would  think this question is more suited to be asked over at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest it would not get through the app store as it is for a very specific and probably quite small audience. It is most likely a good candidate for Business to Business as the equipment dealer can then select who they want to invite to purchase the app (even if the app is free).

There are more details here

https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

The other option is Enterprise Distribution but that is more aimed at in house distribution as it does not use the app store so you will need to find a mechanism of distributing the app. There is also a slightly higher cost to the Enterprise license

Comment: Enterprise Distribution is not an option, because the license specifies you can only distribute the app to employees. Since the dealers are mostly not employees you will be in breach of the license agreement.

Comment: Yes that is true the Enterprise license is only valid if the sub-dealers where part of the same company, it wasn't entirely clear from the original post if they were separate entities which is why I included it as an option but you are correct I should have highlighted this in my original answer

Comment: Nice video about b2b distribution : https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=311